# Filtering and then counting distinct values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is for Excel: I've been tasked with counting distinct records after I have filtered the data.  I have 330 rows with column A containing the 'name' and in Column B I have the name of a test that was done for each 'name', which each 'name' could have taken several iterations of the same test.  The test results are in Column C.

```
Col A -Student  Col B -Exam          Col C - Grade
Student 1       Exam 1              .80
Student 2       Exam 1              .50
Student 3       Exam 1              .90
Student 2       Exam 1              .75
Student 4       Exam 1              .90
Student 5       Exam 1              .55
Student 2       Exam 2              .90
Student 1       Exam 2              .90
....            ....                ...
```

If I filter col B for Exam 1, I want to count the unique number of students that have taken Exam 1.

Answer (score 3):

Found this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A30000<>"")/COUNTIF(A1:A30000,A1:A30000&""))
```

on the [Excel Forum](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-worksheet-functions/365877-count-distinct-values.html)

Tested in on your example and .. it works :-)

Answer (score 1):

Array entered

> {=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(LEN(A1:A8)>0,MATCH(A1:A8,A1:A8,FALSE),""),IF(LEN(A1:A8)>0,MATCH(A1:A8,A1:A8,FALSE),""))*(B1:B9="Exam
>   1")>0,1))}

Note that since FREQUENCY returns one more data point than the source range, that the column B range is actually B1:B9 and this only works if B9 is not equal to Exam 1.

If you want to base the condition on what is filtered rather than on a certain column every time, I don't know of a way to do it with a formula.  If you're not averse to VBA, you could use this simple UDF.

```
Public Function CountUniqueFiltered(rColumn As Range) As Long
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim colUnique As Collection

    Set colUnique = New Collection

    For Each rCell In rColumn.Cells
        If Not rCell.EntireRow.Hidden Then
            On Error Resume Next
                colUnique.Add rCell.Value, CStr(rCell.Value)
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
    Next rCell

    CountUniqueFiltered = colUnique.Count
End Function
```

Comment: What if I want to filter by grade/Col C?  This is just a simplified example datasheet, the real spreadsheet has at least 50 columns of different data and if I filter on any of those columns, I need the distinct 'name' column to change and be able to provide a distinct 'name' count.  I'm using the following to count a filtered column, but not sure if I can use a modified verson to determine distinct:=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(U8:U331,ROW(U8:U331)-MIN(ROW(U8:U331)),,1)),--(U8:U331>=$I$3)). Appreciate any advice you can provide.

Comment: Your post did say "fitlered" didn't it?  I don't know of a way with formulas, but edited my response with some VBA.

Comment: Thank you!  I went ahead and used the VBA code and it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how column B is fitting in here, but...

```
select distinct column_A, count(*)
from table
where column_C = 'A+'
group by column_A
```

Answer (score 0):

In line with thursdaysgeek

```
strFile = Workbooks(1).FullName
''Note HDR=Yes, so column names can be used
strCon = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & strFile _
    & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open strCon
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCT Student, Exam FROM [Sheet4$] " _
       & "WHERE Exam='Exam 1'"

rs.Open strSQL, cn

For i = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
    Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(1, i + 1) = rs.Fields(i).Name
Next

Sheets("Sheet5").Cells(2, 1).CopyFromRecordset rs
```